# Twilio, Google Sheets, No credentials provided

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

Our company is looking for ability to use a service like Twilio to send out SMS messages to several hundred people (RSVP reminders).  Currently, we are using Google Sheets to track the list of people.

I found an entry in Twilio's blog (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html) written by Greg Baugues that outlines how to send SMS messages using JS and Google Sheets.  I copied Greg's JS code into the Google Sheets Script Editor, change out the Account SID and AuthToken with the values provided in my trial account, and then tried to send a single test SMS.  Every time I run the function, I get the following response:

```
Request failed for https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC042b89e7dffb4cb877f82b0c2efc76a7/Messages.json
returned code 401. Truncated server response: 

{"code": 20003, "detail": "Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.", "message": "Authentication Error - No credentials provided", "more_info": ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

To make sure I didn't have some kind of error in my SID and Token, I tried send a test SMS through the web interface, and Python script available on Twilio's website.  Both of these were successful.

Does anyone have any other recommendations?  In the original blog post, I noticed that several other readers have left comments with the same issue.  The authentication part of the original function is:

```
var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  options.headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic" + Utilities.base64Encode("AccountSID:AuthToken")  ##Credentials hidden, obviously
  };
```

I wonder if something has change in Twilio's security settings since this posts was originally shared.

Answer (score 2):

Got it. Very simple Javascript typo. In the options headers, there needs to be a space after Basic. `"Authorization" : "Basic "`

Everything works now. I'll leave this up in case anyone else decides to replicate the same code from the blog post.